# Converting multiple excel files to json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, excel

I am trying to convert `multiple excel files` to `multiple json files`. I have been looking into some `nodejs` libraries, but unsure on which library fits. Is there a `library` or way where can read multiple excel files and convert them to corresponding json files.

I was looking at this particular library.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-json

```
var cv2json = require('../');

var csv_trans = cv2json.xls('./test/test.xls', options /* optional */, function(err, result) {
  if(err)
    console.error(err);
  else 
    console.log(result);
    // result should be a json object or array. 
})
```

I see they are passing a single excel file and converting it to json-object. Is there a way we can pass multiple file argument and get their corresponding json object back.

Answer (score 1):

Just use loop

```
var files = [
  './path/to/file1.xls',
  './path/to/file2.xls'
]

files.forEach(function(file) {
  cv2json.xls(file, function(err, result) {
    // do something with result
  }) 
})
```